# database insert error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, datagridview

Hello guys I have little problem cannot figure why but when im inserting data from `datagridview` rows to datebase got Error occured:

> Invalid column name 'string in row'. Column name or number of supplied
> values does not match table definition.

Here is some lines of my code:

```
try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    comm.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    s = 0;
                    for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < dgvDataList.Columns.Count; columnIndex++)
                    {
                        columnName = dgvDataList.Columns[columnIndex].Name;
                        if (!regex.IsMatch(columnName))
                        { 
                            if (s == 0)
                            {
                                StrQuery = @"CREATE TABLE FileTable (" + columnName + " varchar(255));";
                                comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                s++;
                            }
                            else if (s >= 1)
                            {
                                StrQuery = @"ALTER TABLE FileTable ADD [" + columnName + "] varchar (255);";
                                comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    columnIndex = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < dgvDataList.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        columnName = dgvDataList.Columns[columnIndex].Name;
                        if(!regex.IsMatch(columnName))
                        { 
                            StrQuery = @"INSERT INTO FileTable VALUES ([" + dgvDataList.Rows[i].Cells[columnName].Value + "]);";
                            comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        columnIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I'll be happy for any tips, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the column name really contain `[]`? It seems you spelled it wrong in `ALTER` query.
Also if you don't want your column value contain `[]`, remove it from `INSERT` query.

Edit your `INSERT` query to:

```
StrQuery = @"INSERT INTO FileTable (" + columnName + ") 
            VALUES ('[" + dgvDataList.Rows[i].Cells[columnName].Value + "]');";
```

Comment: Sure it was some syntax problem, thanks.